# How should I slice geometries in a Json file with Geopandas?

Tags: python, java, json, geopandas

My problem is that I can't find a code to automate the generation of another json as an output file to cut and join polygons, this Json file has dictionaries and within these it has coordinates (X,Y).

With the help of Geopandas I was trying to find a code that would cut the overlapping polygons, and with the other non-overlapping polygon just merge with the last polygon, i.e. first find the base of the overlapping polygon, then cut these overlapping ones and with the other non-overlapping polygon just join them, I know I should use geopandas overlap method, with how="union" and "difference".

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please read [ask]. We need more information before we can help you. Please provide an example of the data you’re working with and the code you have tried, along with the complete error messages or an explanation of why the behavior isn’t expected. Try as best you can to provide a full [mre]. Additionally, make sure your question is narrowly focused on one problem only - you can ask multiple questions in multiple posts but each one should be narrowly focused.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.